# Extract values from non-monotonic changes in time series

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

We have a data lake in AWS S3 with sensor records from tens of thousands of sensors sending in data every 5 minutes. I am trying to pull battery lifetime from sensors through AWS Athena (Presto).

For each sample record, every sensor increments its record index by 1. When batteries are taken out / replaced, record index starts at 1 again.

All data from all sensors are in same table and order is based on when received at AWS (cannot assume is sorted). There are duplicates.

Example dataset:

```
+--------+-----------------+------------+---------+
| sensor | samplerecorded  | record     | battery |
+--------+-----------------+------------+---------+
|   2930 | 4/26/2019 22:04 | 1          |     3.3 |
|   2930 | 4/25/2019 22:04 | 5          |       2 |
|   2930 | 4/24/2019 22:04 | 6          |     1.8 |
|   2930 | 4/23/2019 22:04 | 4          |     2.5 |
|   2930 | 4/23/2019 22:04 | 4          |     2.5 |
|   2931 | 4/20/2019 22:04 | 1          |     3.4 |
|   2931 | 4/19/2019 22:04 | 3          |       2 |
|   2930 | 4/22/2019 22:04 | 3          |       3 |
|   2931 | 4/18/2019 22:04 | 2          |       3 |
|   2931 | 4/18/2019 22:04 | 2          |       3 |
|   2931 | 4/17/2019 22:04 | 1          |     3.3 |
|   2931 | 4/17/2019 22:04 | 1          |     3.3 |
|   2931 | 4/17/2019 22:04 | 3          |       2 |
|   2931 | 4/16/2019 22:04 | 2          |     2.5 |
|   2931 | 4/15/2019 22:04 | 1          |       3 |
|   2931 | 4/13/2019 22:04 | 5          |     1.9 |
|   2931 | 4/12/2019 22:04 | 4          |       2 |
|   2931 | 4/11/2019 22:04 | 3          |     2.1 |
|   2930 | 4/21/2019 22:04 | 2          |     2.8 |
|   2930 | 4/20/2019 22:04 | 1          |       3 |
|   2930 | 4/19/2019 22:04 | 8          |       2 |
+--------+-----------------+------------+---------+
```

For each sensor, I want to group complete data sets (record 1 to N, N = row before next (sorted) sample record restarts at "1") and get battery voltage and date at start and end of a data set plus a calculated column with battery lifetime.

Wanted output:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| sensor | date_start | date_end  | bat_start | bat_end | bat_life_days |
+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------+
|   2930 | 4/20/2019  | 4/24/2019 |         3 |     1.8 |             4 |
|   2931 | 4/15/2019  | 4/17/2019 |         3 |       2 |             2 |
|   2931 | 4/17/2019  | 4/24/2019 |       3.3 |     1.8 |             7 |
+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------+
```

Current implementation mostly works, but some noise in data gives bad results here and there. I now have data from start and stop of each data set. Still need to " merge" rows per serialnumber between new battery (>3000 mV) and empty battery (<2000mV) since customers pull batteries on a regular basis when they don't get things to work, which distorts results.

Suggestions on how to achieve this?
And what would be a more optimal way of doing below?

```
WITH partitioned_data AS (
  SELECT 
    cs.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY serialnumber 
      ORDER BY 
        samplerecorded ASC
    ) AS rn 
  FROM 
    crawler_samples cs 
  WHERE 
    serialnumber LIKE '293%' 
    AND -- noise in data
    battVoltage IS NOT NULL 
    AND battVoltage <> 0 
    AND battvoltage > 1000 -- millivolts in source
    ), 
first_sample_table AS (
  SELECT 
    rn AS start_rn, 
    serialnumber AS start_sn, 
    samplerecorded AS t_start, 
    battvoltage AS batt_start, 
    count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY serialnumber) AS reboots 
  FROM 
    partitioned_data 
  WHERE 
    record = 0
), 
-- list of excluded devices
excluded_devices AS (
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT start_sn AS sn 
  FROM 
    first_sample_table 
  WHERE 
    -- devices that sent illegal data at start of dataset
    batt_start = 65535
), 
-- remove excluded devices
filtered_fst AS (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    first_sample_table 
    LEFT JOIN excluded_devices ON first_sample_table.start_sn = excluded_devices.sn 
  WHERE 
    excluded_devices.sn IS NULL
), 
--add the previous battery empty to same row
last_row_table AS (
  SELECT 
    filtered_fst.*, 
    partitioned_data.rn, 
    LAG(partitioned_data.battVoltage, 2) OVER (
      PARTITION BY partitioned_data.serialnumber 
      ORDER BY 
        partitioned_data.samplerecorded
    ) AS batt_end, 
    LAG(
      partitioned_data.samplerecorded, 
      2
    ) OVER (
      PARTITION BY partitioned_data.serialnumber 
      ORDER BY 
        partitioned_data.samplerecorded
    ) AS t_end 
  FROM 
    partitioned_data 
    LEFT JOIN filtered_fst ON partitioned_data.serialnumber = filtered_fst.start_sn 
    AND partitioned_data.rn = filtered_fst.start_rn
), 
-- clean out join in next cte or LAG would be incorrect (WHERE executes first)
cleaned_last_row_table AS (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    last_row_table 
  WHERE 
    start_sn IS NOT NULL
), 
--offset end columns to match start and stop
offset_end AS (
  SELECT 
    start_sn AS serialnumber, 
    start_rn AS rownum, 
    t_start, 
    batt_start, 
    lead(t_end, 1) OVER (
      PARTITION BY start_sn 
      ORDER BY 
        t_start
    ) AS t_end, 
    lead(batt_end, 1) OVER (
      PARTITION BY start_sn 
      ORDER BY 
        t_start
    ) AS batt_end, 
    reboots 
  FROM 
    cleaned_last_row_table
), 
-- append calculated column (easier to read)
FINAL AS (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    date_diff('day', t_start, t_end) AS batt_time_days 
  FROM 
    offset_end 
  WHERE 
    t_start IS NOT NULL 
    AND t_end IS NOT NULL
) 
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  FINAL 
ORDER BY 
  serialnumber, 
  rownum;
```

[image: actual ouput data]

Comment: I don't understand why `date_start` for 2930 is 2019-04-20 rather than 2019-04-21 22:04.   It would probably help if the data were sorted by time for the sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - 2019-04-20 is date when a new sample set starts (########1) for 2930. Tried to compact things slightly as real dates span months/years per data set with record samples coming in from each sensor every 5 mins.